# External User (Guest) E-mail Notifications in Planner

Tags: notifications, microsoft-planner

When I assign a task to a user inside my organization, they receive an e-mail that a task has been assigned to them. However, when a task is assigned to an external/guest user, they do not receive any notification. I have notifications turned on for everyone in the group and I confirmed that they are turned on for the external user as well. Do these e-mails behave differently for external vs. internal users?